# Fluent Hibernate Automapping issues in table definition (all indices not null)

Tags: mysql, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

Title: multiple class with same variable name list has issues in table definition (all indices not null)

lets say i have two class implementing from one interface

```
public interface IInterface1
{
   IList<string> myList {get; set;}
}

public class class1 : IInterface1
{
    IList <string> myList {get; set;}
    public class1()
    {
       myList = new List<string>();
    }
}

public class class2 : IInterface1
{
    IList<string> myList {get; set;}
    public class2()
    {
       myList = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

when the table is created the for myList the table definition would be like

1. class1_id 'not null = true'
2. value
3. class2_id 'not null = true'

when you try to save a value it will fail since it will always have only one id value at a time.

when class1 is saved only only class1_id can be saved and class2_id will be empty this would cause the insert to fail with error

```
'could not insert collection:.....VALUES (?p0, ?p1)]'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I fixed your formatting to SO capabilities.

Comment: @Jim Thanks 

One Work around: Add not-null="false" in the <column name = "class1_id" not-null="false" (Although this is not the best approach) Another work around could be wrapping them in a class or not putting the ilist inside the interface but none of these are gr8 solution